# SQL GROUP BY and COUNT and conditional SUM with column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example of my table.

```
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ UserId │ Status │ Value │
├────────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 1      │ 1      │ 10    │
│ 1      │ 0      │ 5     │
│ 2      │ 0      │ 8     │
│ 2      │ 1      │ 15    │
│ 1      │ 1      │ 10    │
│ 1      │ 0      │ 5     │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

I need to `GROUP BY` rows with `UserId` then `COUNT` total rows in the group, to this point I have no problem but I also want to `SUM(Value)` according `Status` Column. Like `COUNT` my sql give me total sum of group rows but I need result like below :-)

```
┌────────┬──────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ UserId │ SUM(Value) Status=1  │ SUM(Value) Status=0 │
├────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1      │        20            │        10           │
│ 2      │        15            │        8            │
└────────┴──────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

NOTE: This type of query called **Conditional Aggregation** you may search for more about this.

Comment: It is called conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
SELECT USERID,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END ) AS ST1,
SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END ) AS ST2 FROM 
DBO.TABLENAME
GROUP BY USERID
```

Comment: you need to improve your query, what if more than two status code exist.

you may use PIVOT

Comment: It's Dynamic if more then two states then add more case when you need just change column name. @MANthanNPatel if you agree then vat it.

Comment: @MANthanNPatel the question is tagged MySql and there is no PIVOT in MySql. Also Status is obviously a Boolean column.

Comment: Not mention bool, also tagged sql, anyways have a good day : )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data type of `Status` is `BOOLEAN` or `INTEGER` with only `0` and `1` as possible values:

```
SELECT UserId,
       SUM(Status * Value) Status_1,
       SUM((NOT Status) * Value) Status_0
FROM tablename
GROUP BY UserId;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d061b06484a6805f8c974272bf84004).

Comment: this also works, but if status define in string then not work e.g. `status = 'active'` or something :-)

Comment: @Baisnabi This is an answer for the question that you posted and not any other question where status is string. Did you read my answer from the start: "Assuming that the data type of Status..."

Comment: My bad I upvoted you and I thing @PiyushKachhadiya answer first, so ...

Comment: @Baisnabi my comment has nothing to do with your voting. I responded to your comment which mentions that my query would not work if....